# How to find which button assigned to a procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some Excel files. It got some procedures created (the VBA code).
I want to clean up the codes as some are not relevant to that worksheet anymore (they duplicate the file from previous but didn't clean up the code).

What I would need is to figure out, a particular procedure/module was assigned to which button/ratio button on the worksheet. So I can clean up those irrelevant procedures.

Please note that this is "from procedure, find out to which button it is assigned", not "from the button, find out to which procedure it is assigned"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Loop through the buttons and figure out which procedures have been assigned to them.

Comment: That is not possible. It only works the other way round.

Comment: @BigBen: I did think about creating a function/sub, loop through all the button objects in all the worksheets, but not sure which properties of the button objects has the information of "which sub/function" it is assigned to.

Comment: The `OnAction` property

Comment: @BigBen How can I find the collection of controls or buttons on a worksheet? `Worksheet.Controls` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @Toddleson assuming form controls, use the `worksheet.buttons` collection.

Comment: @Rory `Worksheet.Buttons` doesn't exist for me either. I found them in `Worksheet.Shapes` but the `.OnAction` property was blank but I know they buttons are linked to `CommandButton1_Click`. Is this because my button is ActiveX?

Comment: @Toddleson The `buttons` collection is deprecated, but it does exist. It won't work for activex controls, but this exercise would be pointless for them anyway, since the routine will always just be the commandbutton's `Click` event.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to loop through all the Shapes in the worksheet and find out the OnAction properties

```
Function LoopShapes()

Dim shape As shape

For Each shape In Sheet3.Shapes
    Debug.Print shape.Name, "   ", TypeName(shape), "   ", shape.OnAction
Next

End Function
```